# What's meaning of word くじけずに

Tags: translation, meaning

「くじけずに、前を向きたい」
I can't find this word in vocabulary, but somebody me said that its meaning "Don't give up" or "Work hard". But I'm not sure in it.
  If it's truth, the sentence must be "Don't give up, I want to be suitable for you"? or maybe correctly "Don't give up, I want to see(to meet?) you" 
Thanks for answer

Comment: That is not a word;  It's three words.

Answer (score 3):

How about "keep going, I want to think positively."?

くじける means collapse, falter, stagger. ず is a old verbal auxiliary of ない which is used as negative.

The Literal translation of 前を向く is "face forward" but it is often used as the meaning of " to think positively".

Comment: Thanks. It's still difficult for me, but you're Japanese and know it better than I know. I will  try

Comment: @Alai i think the translation might be くじけず に (when you get discouraged, literally in discourage moment) 前を向きたい (i want to look forward). So in English it might meant: when you get discouraged, try to look forward and move on (think positive). So it is synonymous with 'don't give up or try again'.